# simple C structure usage generate errors with clang -fsyntax-only

Tags: c, clang

Here is the simple C source file:

```
struct data{
  int a;
  char * b;
  double c;
};

struct data mydata;
struct data *ptr;

ptr = &mydata;

ptr->a = 1;
ptr->b = NULL;
ptr->c = 0.1;
```

When I run the command:

```
clang -fsyntax-only source.c
```

I have this output:

```
source.c:11:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
ptr = &mydata;
^
source.c:11:1: error: redefinition of 'ptr' with a different type: 'int' vs 'struct data *'
source.c:9:14: note: previous definition is here
struct data *ptr;
             ^
source.c:13:1: error: unknown type name 'ptr'
ptr->a = 1;
^
source.c:13:4: error: expected identifier or '('
ptr->a = 1;
   ^
source.c:14:1: error: unknown type name 'ptr'
ptr->b = NULL;
^
source.c:14:4: error: expected identifier or '('
ptr->b = NULL;
   ^
source.c:15:1: error: unknown type name 'ptr'
ptr->c = 0.1;
^
source.c:15:4: error: expected identifier or '('
ptr->c = 0.1;
   ^
1 warning and 7 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following four lines are only valid if they are present in a *function*:

```
ptr = &mydata;    
ptr->a = 1;
ptr->b = NULL;
ptr->c = 0.1;
```

(`mydata` and `ptr` are understood to be global variables).

If you enclose them in a function with prototype `int main()`, then all will be well. (The C compiler will expect to find a function called `main`, and the prototype I've given you is one that the C standard accepts.)

Answer (score 1):

C cannot parse statements like that. It is not Python :-)

You need to enclose your statements in a function. For example:

```
struct data{
  int a;
  char * b;
  double c;
};

struct data mydata;

int main() {
    struct data *ptr;
    ptr = &mydata;

    ptr->a = 1;
    ptr->b = NULL;
    ptr->c = 0.1;
}
```